# How do I integrate seats.io to website

Tags: html

I'm a beginner to the simple coding and I have bumped into a problem.

I'm not sure what happened but I copy pasted the javascript code into my codes.

Sorry for this, but I have no idea what to do now, and I really got to make this work by the end of today.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="no">
    <head>
        <meta name="oving4" charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/JScript.js"></script>
        <style>
            div.background {
                background: url(http://www.gosugamers.net/uploads/files/44-1385563461.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
                border: 2px solid black;
                background-size: cover;
                width: 100%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }

            div.transbox {
                margin: 300px;
                background-color: white;
                border: 1px solid black;
                opacity: 0.8;
                filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
            }

            div.transbox p {
                margin: 10%;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #000000;
            }

        </style>
        <title> AuLan 2016</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="index.html">AuLan</a> 
        </div>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li id="menus"><a href="index.html">Forside</a></li>
            <li id="menus"><a href="info.html">Informasjon</a></li>
            <li id="menus"><a href="regler.html">Regler</a></li>
            <li id="menus"><a href="crew.html">Crew</a></li>
            <li id="menus"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt oss</a></li>
            <li id="menus"><a <a class="active" href="seat.php">Seatmap</a></li>
            <li id="menus"><a href="time.html">Tidsskjema</a>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <div class="background">
                <div class="transbox">
                    <p><h2> Seatmap</h2></p>

                    <p> Velg sete </p>

                    <div id="chartDesigner">
                        <script>
                            new seatsio.SeatingChartDesigner({
                                divId: "chartDesigner",
                                designerKey: "0da00aaf-755c-4a1b-9799-b31cbcc899b3"
                                        chartKey: "0b8e566a-1cb5-41ca-93bb-9209f143734a"
                            }).render();
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer> &copy; 2016 AuLan</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What is not working ?

Comment: it seems you forgot to include the proper js file. Take a look at their example page http://www.seats.io/demos/renderer#zero-config